# Is it possible to use Oracle PL/SQL Procedure in my JSP Scriptlet code?

Tags: oracle, jsp, plsql

```
<%
        // PL/SQL PROCEDURE CODE
%>
```

I want to use Oracle PL/SQL Procedure in my JSP Scriptlet code. Is it possible or not?

Comment: You can call PL/SQL procedures through REST using ORDS. [Find out more](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/appdev/rest.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL is written only in Oracle Database Schema. It is not possible to use it in JSP Scriptlet. Only SQL Statements can be written in Scriptlet.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. Inside JSPs you can only write java code. The reason is that JSPs are compiled to servlet java classes.

Comment: you can still call the PL SQL stored procedure using JDBC e.g. <br/> String preparedSql = "{call insertEmployee(?,?,?,?)}";
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall(preparedSql); <br/> cstmt.setString(2, "ana");
cstmt.setString(3, "tester");
cstmt.setDouble(4, 2000); <br/> But this is still jave code. PL SQL code is written in the DB Schema